# Is there any security threat with open WiFi connection in 2023 for online banking?

Tags: tls, wifi

According to its website, my bank does not recommend to use open wifi networks for online banking without VPN.
Why is that?
I understand, that 10-20 years ago many site and application sent the data unencrypted. But I haven't found any website in the last years that does not use HTTPS? Why is a VPN connection more secure than HTTPS?

Comment: Nothing's changed much in 10 years.